# Assign industry codes according to ranges in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to assign overall industry/parent codes to a `data.frame` (`df` below) containing more detailed/child codes (called `ChildCodes` below). The following data serves to illustrate my data.frame containing the detailed codes:

```
> df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(110,101,200,2041,3651,2102)))
> names(df) <- c('Id','ChildCodes')
> df
  Id ChildCodes
1  1        110
2  2        101
3  3        200
4  4       2041
5  5       3651
6  6       2102
```

The industry/parent codes are in the `.csv` file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5qtb7ysys1ar0lj/IndustryCodes.csv

The problem for me is the format of the `.csv` file. The file shows the parent/industry code in column 1 and ranges of child/detailed codes in the next 2 columns. Here is a subset:

```
> IndustryCodes <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,1,2,5,6),c(100,200,2040,2100,3650),c(199,299,2046,2199,3651)))
> names(IndustryCodes) <- c('IndustryGroup','LowerRange','UpperRange')
> IndustryCodes
  IndustryGroup LowerRange UpperRange
1             1        100        199
2             1        200        299
3             2       2040       2046
4             5       2100       2199
5             6       3650       3651
```

So that `ChildCode` 110 corresponds industry group 1, 2041 to industry code 2 etc. How do best assign the industry/parent codes (IndustryGroup) to `df` in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sapply to get the Industry code for every child code:

```
sapply(df$ChildCodes, 
       function(x) IndustryCodes$IndustryGroup[IndustryCodes$LowerRange <= x & 
                                               x <= IndustryCodes$UpperRange])
# [1] 1 1 1 2 6 5
```